# Add drop down on button click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am early bee for angularjs. How to add drop downs in button click.

For example

If I Click the button one drop down should be display in html. If I click second time one more drop down should append in html.

Comment: You use ng-repeat on some array in the scope, and display a drop-down inside the ng-repeat. On button click, you add an element to this array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-repeat on an array in the scope. For example in your controller, you declare a $scope array, like: $scope.items=[] and use ng-repeat on this array like: `enter code here`ng-repeat="item in items" 
Within the div tag containing your ng-repeat, add a  tag to display a drop down.

You can have a look at this plunker, which does a similar thing. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/gdiuPCxHHopb15kcSAZH?p=preview